# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property in GetAbbreviatedMonthName

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting following error

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
property 'System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(int).
```

While I try to add Month Abbreviated Name in a string list like follow.

```
List<string> monList = new List<string>();
monList.Add(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(3));
```

I don't know what is the problem in this. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetAbbreviatedMonthName` is instance method so you have to have an instance of `DateTimeFormatInfo` class to call that method.

Use `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` to get `DateTimeFormatInfo` instance for current culture:

```
monList.Add(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(3));
```